# How to implement a custom number format that will look like "30c - $19.70"

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a spreadsheet for keeping track of my stock trades. This column will be called "Risk" and it will show how much money I want to risk per share on trade and at what price I will have to close the trade at if prices go against my position. So, for example, if I bought shares of Ford at $20 and was willing to risk losing 30 cents per share before closing the trade, I want to be able to type "30 19.70" in a cell and have the custom number format change it to "30c - $19.70". How do I implement this?

I have tried using the following custom number format on Google Spreadsheets but it doesn't work:

```
0 "c - " $0.00
```

I input the following into a cell: `30 19.70`

I want this result to be: `30c - $19.70`

But I'm getting this output: `30 19.70`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, this is not possible for several reasons:

- your entry: `30 19.70` is not a number. it's a text string. that's why `0 "c - " $0.00` will never work because those zeros are trying to find numbers to catch up on them, but your entry is not a number.
- text can't be divided in between with `"c - "`. you can have `@"c - "` or `"c - "@`, but `@"c - "@.@` will output: `30 19.70c - $30 19.70.30 19.70`

best you can do is to enter `30` in one cell and `19.70` in another cell and use a formula in a 3rd cell:

**`=A145&"c - $"&TEXT(B145, "##.#0")`**

[image]

or: **`=JOIN("c - $",INDEX(SPLIT(A150," "),1,1),TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A150," "),1,2),"##.#0"))`**

[image]